# What is the inverse of the linear map $T(\phi) = \phi(1)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over the reals, and define $T: \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}, V) \to V$ by $T(\phi) = \phi(1)$. I want to find the inverse of this map. One idea I came up with was $T^{-1}v = \psi$ where $\psi(\lambda) = \lambda v$. But I have trouble showing that $T^{-1}T = I$.

Comment: Here $\mathbb R$ is the one-dimensional vector space, and $\{1\}$ is taken as its basis. Then $T(\phi) = \phi(1)$ sets up a one-to-one correspondence between $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}, V)$ and $V$.  So what is the inverse of that?

Comment: @Gedgar $T$ maps every linear functional to its evaluation at $1$, which is a vector. but I can't seem to figure out what the opposite of that would be...$T^{-1}$ maps every vector to some functional that i am not sure how to define.

Comment: @a6623 try to reverse engineer this. Suppose you were given $S \colon V \to \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}, V)$ which is inverse to $T$. What do you know about $S$? In particular, for any $v \in V$, what is the value of $S(v)$ at $1 \in \mathbb{R}$? Now recall what you know about bases, and try to use GEdgar's hint that $\{1\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Oh I got it! So my original idea was correct then

Comment: @a6623 yes, that's right. I encourage you to write the details out in your own answer. If you get stuck, you can update your original question - people will be happy to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the help of the comments, here is how to see that the $\psi$ as I have defined above, is indeed the inverse.

First, $TT^{-1}(v) = T\psi = \psi(1)$. But by definition of $\psi$, $\psi(1) = 1 \cdot v = v$ so $TT^{-1} = I$.

On the other hand, $T^{-1}T(\phi) = T^{-1}(\phi(1)) = \psi$ where $\psi(\lambda) = \lambda \cdot \phi(1)$. Now, notice that $\phi(\lambda) = \phi(\lambda \cdot 1) = \lambda \cdot \phi(1)$ by linearity, so we have that $\psi = \phi$ (in this case) and $T^{-1}T = I$.

Comment: Well done, +1. For completeness, you might want to justify that $\psi$ is linear, even though it is straightforward. And if you are in the mood, you might think about how you would prove the following more general fact, of which your question is a special case: let $V, W$ be vector spaces over a field $F$, and suppose $V$ has a basis given by $\{v_{i}\}_{i \in I}$ for some index set $I$. Then there is an $F$-linear isomorphism $\mathcal{L}(V, W)  \to W^{I}$ sending $\varphi$ to $\{\varphi(v_{i})\}_{i \in I}$.